# In CSS How do I Highlight all Images from a Link and apply a Border around those Images and apply to the whole Website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a Complete Noob still learning Javascript/CSS

```
a:visited img {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
}
```

This works for onclick but I want this code to appear on all Images that I have already clicked on in bulk without reclicking them from a specific URL that has a PID number that holds 50 image at a time when viewing the images you saved in your favorites. How do I do that?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. We need to know your HTML structure, and it would help if you could explain the desired effect in more detail, maybe with an additional diagram. Check out [how to create a MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay then is it possible to use that code in Bulk without re clicking?

Comment: The Website is Rule34.XXX Ive looked at the site code and I think I need to Loop through all image src. But i dont know how to do that..

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what you're after, but here are some options for you to try:

This will apply to all images within an anchor tag

```
a img {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
}
```

Unvisited Link

```
a:link img {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
}
```

Mouseover link

```
a:hover img {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
}
```

Selected link

```
a:active img {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
}
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp).  Hope that helps!